# HTML5 + JavaScript, type of input

Tags: javascript, html

When I declare JS.

```
var test = $("#test").val();
```

Then the "number validaion" is not working on the browser side.

```
<input type="number" id="test" name="test" required>
```

Is there any chance to declare $("#test") and use HTML5 in input validation as well (such as required, number validation etc.)? Or I have to to do it on JS side.

It have to be declared to use it later in my AJAX post scipt.

Thanks :)

Comment: Don't rely on client side validation since it can be avoided easily. Take a look here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation

Comment: Also, in which browser did you test this?

Comment: Google chrome, the latest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `parseInt("stringOfNumber")` to get integer from string. When inputting data, you write strings, not numbers.

Comment: Yeah but I just wonder if there is any way to use browser HTML5 validation and declare some of the id's in JS.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you use the input type number in HTML5:

```
<input type="number" name="cost">
```

Here is a working example of the http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_number.

If you want to add validation try this:

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="cost">
```

Here is a working example of the pattern attribute http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_pattern

Note: Both the input type number and the pattern attribute have limited browser support.

Comment: I have tried those already, when I declared input to my JS it seems to doesn't work.

I have tried with patern etc.

Comment: input type=number does not work in firefox. so to make it work you can use pattern it works in firefox.

Comment: There is validation even on empty patern but without declaration in JS code.

Comment: I have tried, it is not working, when the input id is declared in js, I think the one way to validate is using js code.

Comment: yeah buddy den you should do it with js

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it's Not a Number, and then invert it.

```
if(!isNaN(test))
{
    // Is a number
}
```

If you use jQuery, you could use

```
if($.isNumeric(test))
{
    // Is a number
}
```

Don't rely on Client Side validation though, as it can be easily avoided and some browsers don't support it. E.g: JavaScript validation can be avoided by disabling JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah I know but I just wonder if there is any was to use HTML5 browser validation and js as well.

Comment: I know that it can be avoided, I used the 2nd validation on back-end php side.

Comment: @Potar Back-end validation is the way to go, in which case you can use the client-side validation. Just keep in mind that not all browsers support the HTML5 validation.